# What is the ferry schedule from Male to Thulusdhoo in the Maldives?

Tags: ferries, maldives

I am looking into options for public ferries from Male to Thulusdhoo on a Friday or Saturday.

The information I researched so far is a bit confusing:

- There is the [official MTCC schedule](http://www.mtcc.com.mv/route-map-schedule/route-301-north-male-province-dhiffushi-huraa-and-himmafushi), which mentions a 14:30
  departure on Saturday (route 301), which I can't seem to find
  [here](http://www.atolltransfer.com/ferry-routes-c17sd). However, I can query it on [Wild Maldives](http://wildmaldives.com/en/ferry-schedule) too, which I assume uses the timings from MTCC.
- [This page](http://www.cokesbeach.com/getting-to-thulusdhoo-maldives/) and [this one](http://varietystay.com/blogs/transfer-to-thulusdhoo.aspx) list a Saturday ferry at 15:30 (contradicting the 14:30 timing on the other pages) and a
  night ferry on Friday at 22:00 or 22:30, respectively which are also
  mentioned on [Budget Maldives](http://budgetmaldives.co/en/thulusdhoo/) but again not on the "official" timetables. Can anyone confirm any of these
  timings or provide an up-to-date schedule, especially for the Friday ferry?
- I am also wondering where these ferries depart. Villingili Ferry
  Terminal is mentioned as well as "the quay located opposite Marry
  Browns fast food restaurant". Can someone confirm the exact location?

Lastly, if the Friday ferry is still running how much time should we plan to get to the port from the airport and what's the best mode of transportation for that?

Answer (score 4):

I think the times are contradicting because they are for two different ferries. 1430 is for the MTCC ferry, and 1530 appears to be for a ferry branded "Tharika 2". "Tharika 2" definitely departs from near MarryBrown. Also, there doesn't seem to be a ferry on Fridays.

As for getting to the port from airport, the airport ferry will take around 10-15 minutes or so to get to Male, and from there a taxi could take you to the port near Marrybrown in like 10 minutes max.

source: I live in Male.